# Visual Studio Code intellisense on React component using typescript with union types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

So i have a project in Typescript using Create-React-App and i am using Visual Studio Code as my editor.

Intellisense generally works perfectly fine, however in this one scenario it doesn't work as expected.

If i have an interface:

```
interface A { name: string }
interface B extends A { type: 'B'; myProp: string }
interface C extends A {type: 'C'; secondProp: string}
```

if i then have a react component whose props are:

```
const Component: React.SFC<B | C> = props => {}
```

If i then in another component create an instance of Component in the render method and do something like:

```
<Component type='B' />
```

i don't get intellisense for the property 'myProp', if i type myPop in the component and try to assign an object or something it will error saying expecting a string. So it does seem that it recognises the props, just wont popup on the autocomplete part of intellisense.

Just a bit annoying that it doesn't offer 'myProp' in case of B or 'secondProp' in case of C in the list of intellisens autocompletes.

Anyone offer any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to [TypeScript issue #26004](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26004).  Feel free to file a new TypeScript issue and cite that one.

Comment: Thanks, i have raised a github issue on typescript as you suggested.